# Playing Consecutive ads in android/ios

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, ads

I am using dart to create an app. But even if your solution is not dart, it would be appreciated.

I have button saying "Watch 2 ads for 200 coins".
How would I make a function for two ads 30sec or 15 sec... to play simultaneously without the user having to press the back arrow or the x and for it to go back to the home page? I've seen other devs do this in their games, but after spending hours trying to find out how, I still don't know.

### Is it possible?

edit:  Im planning to use admob. Havent started the code for the project yet, Just bringing the ideas together. Im learning flutter/dart atm because i'm relatively new. 
conseutively, one after the other with no input from the user.

Comment: You asked why your question is getting downvoted. I suspect it’s because the community is expecting more details on what you’ve tried, even though it’s not yet working. Given hours of research, you’ve surely developed some ideas, and tried some code. Sharing that and explaining what’s failing will help lead to better answers.

Comment: It would also be useful to know what advertising platform you’re using, as the code may vary between them, based on what hooks are available to you based on the current state. (I’m assuming you don’t _really_ want the ads to play _simultaneously_, but rather _sequentially_?)

Comment: right. Thanks jeremy. Im planning to use admob.  Havent started the code for the project yet, Just bringing the ideas together. Im learning flutter/dart atm. No I mean, conseutively, one after the other with no input from the user.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you've got a function `playAd()` that opens a new Activity, and returns when the user closes the ad:

```
void playAdNTimes(int n) async{
  for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
    await playAd();
  }
}
```

The basic logic is to play another one as soon as the previous one is closed automatically